# How to pass args to args in pythons Popen?

Tags: python

```
import subprocess

command = ["wine"]

arguments = ['/root/Desktop/COLDHEART/exploits/eternalblue/Eternalblue-2.2.0.exe', ' --inconfig /root/Desktop/COLDHEART/exploits/eternalblue/Eternalblue-2.2.0.0.xml', '--targetip 0.0.0.0']

command.extend(arguments)

proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

print(proc)

print("\n Done")
```

So im using subprocess.Popen to get the output from a command. The command is running technically 2 programs, wine and the eternalblue.exe. I need to pass args to the eternalblue.exe but I get errors. It seems to take any args I pass and try to use them for wine instead of the exe.

Answer (score 0):

According to Python Documents,

```
import shlex, subprocess
command_line = raw_input()
## /bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
args = shlex.split(command_line)
print args
##['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd',"echo '$MONEY'"]
p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```

You just need to split your arguments into two elements. For example, 
' --inconfig /root/Desktop/COLDHEART/exploits/eternalblue/Eternalblue-2.2.0.0.xml' --> '--inconfig', '/root/Desktop/COLDHEART/exploits/eternalblue/Eternalblue-2.2.0.0.xml'

Comment: Hi @Elijah if you liked the answer or have any comments let me know. If you feel it is useful please accept the answer. Thanks